# slideshow with button pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I want to create automatic slideshow with buttons that I can click to see one of slides in the slideshow. If I click one of the buttons, the slideshow begins from the slide paired with the clicked button ( for better understanding, let say there are 3 image slides and three buttons and each button is paired with each one of those slides). If I don't click the buttons, just like the automatic slideshow, I want each button focused (.focus()) (Like when the first image slide comes up, the first button will be focused. second image slide -> second button.focus() and so on)

So far, I have done the automatic slideshow using setInterval. The automatic focusing buttons do not start at the same time when the slideshow starts. The first button will be focused when second image comes up and each button is eventually focused in order but it doesn't match with slides.

This is my jquery functions for slideshow and buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    $('div.dotstyle button:nth-child('+i+')').focus();
    i++;
    if(i == 4){i = 0;}
    },  6000);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#wallpaper #info-slide > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
    $('#wallpaper #info-slide > div:first-child').fadeOut(2000).next().fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('#wallpaper #info-slide');
    },  6000);
});
```

This is HTML code

```
   <div id = "wallpaper">
        <div id = 'info-slide'>
            <div><img src="photo1.jpg"/></div>
            <div><img src="photo2.jpg"/></div>
            <div><img src="photo3.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class ="dotstyle"><!-- Pagination -->
            <button>1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is css for buttons (you might want to know)

```
.dotstyle button {
outline: none;
margin-left: 20px;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 50%;
text-indent: -999em; /* make the text accessible to screen readers */
}   

.dotstyle button:hover,
.dotstyle button:focus {
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I do not want to set the first button focused outside of setInterval function because I think that the feature that I explain above, assigning each slide to each button so that I can click the button to see assigned slide and the slideshow starts from that slide, would need the click function to detect the user's click and change the image using index. I actually wanted to ask for solution of this feature. If there is better idea please tell me.

So my first question is how to fix automatic focusing buttons that start at the same time with the slide show and the second questions is for the better idea of implementing the feature.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why you don't put all the code in the same `setInterval()` function on the same `$(document).ready(function(){...}` event?

Comment: @MarBer good point. I actually tried that but it had the same problem. Unless I set the first button focused outside of **setInterval()**,  automatic focusing always happens after the second image comes up. A problem I forgot to mention is that when the third button gets focused, **focus()** remains for two images and the first button gets focused.  I don't think there is an index problem though. Everything is fine if I set the first button focused outside of the function but then I think it would be hard to detect a click of a button using **click()**.

Comment: The initial status of slider have to be defined out of `setInterval()` function, this is a start point in the timeline of slider animations, the last focused button remains because you start your iterator `i` from 1 and when it is equals to 4 you set to 0 and not at 1. Over your question I suggest you to use the `get()` function for get the element wich you want to animate/focus, only for have more clean code, the link at the documentation [Jquery API get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this script, for me work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = $('#info-slide div'), //all slider images
        buttons = $('.dotstyle button'),//all dot buttons
        iterator = 0;

    //set the start point of slider
    $(buttons).get(0).focus();
    $(images.get(0)).fadeIn(800);

    //every 6 seconds
    setInterval(function() { 
        //save shown image ad focus button
        var now_button = buttons.get(iterator),
            now_image = $(images.get(iterator))

        iterator += 1;//iterator for nex image

        //if is the last image go to first
        if (iterator == images.length) {
            iterator = 0;
        }


        $(now_image).fadeOut(2000);//hide shown image
        $(now_button).blur();//not focus button
        $(images.get(iterator)).fadeIn(2000);//show next image
        buttons.get(iterator).focus()//focus next button

    }, 6000);
})
```

I suppose a css for images:

```
#info-slide div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:  none;
}
```

I hope this can hel you.

Comment: It works nicely. Thank you. And I have one more question. I used your code and it finally worked after I  added "$("#wallpaper #info-slide > div:gt(0)").hide();" at the beginning of the function. Does "$("#wallpaper #info-slide > div:gt(0)").hide();" mean the same as "display: none" ?

Comment: So I either add  "display: none" to a css for #info-slide div or add "$("#wallpaper #info-slide > div:gt(0)").hide();" in jquery function?

Comment: By the jQuery reference: _The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), ...._ [jQueri API](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), the CSS I've put in my answer you can see the `display: none` rule for all the div children of info-slide, if you prefer to use jQuery to hide elemnts is your choice, CSS can be more faster then jQuery, in my opinion this rule is a CSS rule and I see no constraints to use jQuery for this purpose